# Adding a Line In An XML Code Using PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

I need to add a tag in my XML code using PowerShell.

The XML code is an ASP.NET config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="false" />
    <legacyImpersonationPolicy enabled="true" />
    <alwaysFlowImpersonationPolicy enabled="false" />
    <SymbolReadingPolicy enabled="1" />
    <shadowCopyVerifyByTimestamp enabled="true" />
  </runtime>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" />
</configuration>
```

I Need to add `<generatePublisherEvidence_enabled = "False" />` after `<runtime>` and do it using PowerShell.

```
$aspnetConfig= 'C:\Users\Desktop\Aspnet.config' 
$doc = (Get-Content $aspnetConfig) -as [Xml] $newXMlElement = $doc.CreateAttribute("getpublisherEvidence_enabled") 
$newXmlElement.Value = "False" 
$doc.configuration.runtime.Attributes.Append($newXMlElement)  
$doc.save($aspnetConfig)
```

Comment: I want my code to look like

Comment: $aspnetConfig= 'C:\Users\Desktop\Aspnet.config'
$doc = (Get-Content $aspnetConfig) -as [Xml]
$newXMlElement =$doc.CreateAttribute("getpublisherEvidence_enabled")
$newXmlElement.Value = "False" 
$doc.configuration.runtime.Attributes.Append($newXMlElement)
$doc.save($aspnetConfig)

Comment: I just want <getpublisherEvidence_enabled= "False" /> appended below runtime

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that by `<generatePublisherEvidence_enabled = "False" />` you actually mean that underscore is a space so that it becomes `<generatePublisherEvidence enabled = "False" />`.
If that's the case, this is how you would do that.

```
$aspnetConfig= "C:\Users\Desktop\Aspnet.config"
$doc = (Get-Content $aspnetConfig) -As [Xml]
$newXmlElement = $doc.CreateElement('generatePublisherEvidence')
$newXMlElement.SetAttribute('enabled','False')
$doc.configuration.runtime.InsertBefore($newXMlElement, $doc.configuration.runtime.legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy)
$doc.Save($aspnetConfig)
```

Comment: I want to insert under runtime

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="false" />
    <legacyImpersonationPolicy enabled="true" />
    <alwaysFlowImpersonationPolicy enabled="false" />
    <SymbolReadingPolicy enabled="1" />
    <shadowCopyVerifyByTimestamp enabled="true" />
  </runtime>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" />
</configuration>

Comment: before <legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled = "false"/>

Comment: Ah sorry @chetankini, I misunderstood where you wanted the element. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank You @Ben Guenter!! do you know of a function that could replace <legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="false"/> to <generatePublisherEvidence enabled = "false"/>

Comment: Im trying to replace a line in a webconfig file and need to know how to replace stuff in xml using powershell

Comment: Yeah @chetankini, You could probably use the $doc.configuration.runtime.ReplaceChild function. 

As a pro powershell tip, you can pipe an object to 'Get-Member' to see what methods are available on that item. For example I found the ReplaceChild function by $doc.configuration.runtime | Get-Member.